# Separar string por quantidade de caracteres

Tags: c#, .net, string, conversão-de-tipo

Estou desenvolvendo um componente para ler o arquivo enviado pela **DataPrev** com a relação de obituários mensais. Esse arquivo é um **TXT** e a cada 210 caracteres é uma pessoa diferente.

A documentação pode ser vista neste *link*: [SISOBI](http://www.dataprev.gov.br/servicos/arqsisobi.shtm).

Eu estou acostumado a separar dados assim através de um delimitador, usando o `Split()`, porém esse em especial não possui nenhum, e é separado por quantidade de caracteres.

Eu fiz a `Action` para enviar o arquivo **TXT** para a aplicação, e ler os dados contidos no mesmo.

Ex:

```
string exemplo = "13032015joao";
```

Dessa *string*, necessito retirar os dados e colocar em variáveis, como:

```
int dia = 13;
int mes = 03;
int ano = 2015;
string nome = joao;
```

A quantidade de caracter é fixo, exemplo:

Dia sempre será 2 caracteres, e após ele sempre virá o mês com 2 caracteres, e após o ano... E assim até terminar os 210 caracteres.

Utilizando o `Split()` caso tivesse um delimitador, ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
var exemplo = "13|03|2015|joao";
 string[] stringSeparators = new string[] { "|" };
            var result = nomeDescrypt.Split(stringSeparators, StringSplitOptions.None);

var dia = Convert.ToInt32(result[0]);
var Mes= Convert.ToInt32(result[1]);
var Ano= Convert.ToInt32(result[2]);
var Nome= Convert.ToInt32(result[3]);
```

Minha dúvida é: Como separar uma *string*, delimitando por quantidade de caracteres?

Meu *controller* para ler o arquivo está assim:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {
            //verifica se o arquivo está nulo
            if (file == null)
            {
                TempData["MensagemError"] = "Erro ao realizar o upload do arquivo!";
                return View("Index");
            }

            //Salvar o arquivo txt
            string path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Uploads/" + file.FileName));
            file.SaveAs(path);

            //Realiza a leitura do arquivo txt
            var fileContents = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path);

            //testar se está lendo o arquivo
        TempData["Mensagem"] = fileContents;

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

Exemplo de layot:

```
000028000280000016427201412310000000000MARCIO SEARA RIBEIRO                                                        MARIA PETANIA DE OLIVEIRA SEARA 19780306201412319442067052500000000000000000000007657          
000028000290000016428201412310000000000MAIRE VALENTIM DA SILVA                                                     MAIRE VALENTIM DA SILVA         19281105201412310387867350700000000000000000000007657
```

Comment: O que acontece quando o registro tem menos de 210 caracteres? O layout é preenchido com espaços?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez Será sempre 210 caracteres, pois o layout é preenchido com espaços ou "0". Adicionei um Exemplo na pergunta.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

O método que você está procurando é o [`Substring()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=net-6.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397):

```
using static System.Convert;
using static System.Console;
                    
public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var exemplo = "13032015joao";
        var dia = ToInt32(exemplo.Substring(0, 2));
        var mes = ToInt32(exemplo.Substring(2, 2));
        var ano = ToInt32(exemplo.Substring(4, 4));
        var nome = exemplo.Substring(8);
        WriteLine(dia);
        WriteLine(mes);
        WriteLine(ano);
        WriteLine(nome);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/AwcYVm). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ag5jsQ). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/SplitPosition.cs).

É possível fazer algumas coisas para automatizar a execução do código. Ele pode ficar mais curto e generalizado, mas a lógica é uma pouco mais complexa. Só para referência a forma mais genérica:

```
using System;
using static System.Console;
using System.Collections.Generic;
                    
public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var exemplo = "13032015joao";
        //o último elemento poderia ser 200, por exemplo
        //o que se for garantido que ele tenha o tamanho, evitaria o if no método
        var partes = SplitFixed(exemplo, new List<int>() {2, 2, 4, 0});
        foreach(var parte in partes) {
            WriteLine(parte);
        }
        //poderia fazer as conversões aqui e jogar nas variáveis individuais
        
        //alternativa com tipos, não sei se compensa o esforço
        //para fazer certo daria o mesmo trabalho que fazer manualmente
        //poucos casos esta forma seria realmente mais vantajosa e o ideal é que a conversão
        //fosse feita através de lambdas contendo o código de conversão e não com tipos
        var partes2 = SplitFixedTyped(exemplo, new List<Tuple<int, Type>>() {
            new Tuple<int, Type>(2, typeof(int)), 
            new Tuple<int, Type>(2, typeof(int)),
            new Tuple<int, Type>(4, typeof(int)),
            new Tuple<int, Type>(0, typeof(string))});
        foreach(var parte in partes2) {
            WriteLine("Dado: {0} - Tipo {1}", parte, parte.GetType());
        }
        
    }
    public static List<String> SplitFixed(string texto, List<int> tamanhos) {
        var partes = new List<String>();
        var posicao = 0;
        foreach(var tamanho in tamanhos) {
            if (tamanho > 0) { //padronizei que 0 significa que deve ir até o fim
                partes.Add(texto.Substring(posicao, tamanho));
            } else {
                // o ideal é que não tenha essa parte e todos os tamanhos sejam definidos
                //o 0 só pode ser usado como último parâmetro.
                partes.Add(texto.Substring(posicao));
            }
            posicao += tamanho;
        }
        return partes;
    }
    //esta implementação é um pouco ingênua, não funciona em todas as situações mas funciona com o básico
    public static List<object> SplitFixedTyped(string texto, List<Tuple<int, Type>> tamanhos) {
        var partes = new List<object>();
        var posicao = 0;
        foreach(var tamanho in tamanhos) {
            if (tamanho.Item1 > 0) { //padronizei que 0 significa que deve ir até o fim
                partes.Add(Convert.ChangeType(texto.Substring(posicao, tamanho.Item1), tamanho.Item2));
            } else {
                // o ideal é que não tenha essa parte e todos os tamanhos sejam definidos
                //o 0 só pode ser usado como último parâmetro.
                partes.Add(texto.Substring(posicao));
            }
            posicao += tamanho.Item1;
        }
        return partes;
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/oBHADO). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/eMEfRb). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/SplitPosition2.cs).

Uma solução genérica pode ser útil se você tiver que lidar com vários arquivos de colunas de tamanho fixo com *layout* diferentes. Mas quando vai fazer algo genérico tem que pensar bem em todas as possibilidades, é bom garantir que os parâmetros estão em ordem. Eu fiz rapidinho sem considerar tudo o que pode acontecer.

Na época que eu fiz não existia [`Span`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.span-1?view=net-5.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) e [tuplas por valor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/195460/101) como existem hoje, então este código pode ser otimizado.

Comment: Achei muito interessante este método vou usá-lo e verificar outras possibilidades também. Só mais uma dúvida. Como proceder para verificar até o fim da string, quando for uma lista de dados? EX: a string seria: **13032015joao14032015Juca** Neste exemplo, a cada 12 caracteres, trata-se de um novo item.

Comment: @RenilsonAndrade Se eu entendi o que você que é a mesma coisa: `"13032015joao14032015Juca".Substring(0, 12)` e depois `"13032015joao14032015Juca".Substring(12, 12)`

Comment: Sim, o problema é que não sei a quantidade de vezes que irá se repetir. Sei somente que serão 12, utilizando este exemplo como base.

Comment: É só fazer um laço e verificar se a posição mais o tamanho a ser lido é maior ou igual ao tamanho do texto total. Se não conseguir fazer acho que dá uma boa pergunta nova já que é um problema diferente do original desta pergunta.

Comment: Estou tentando fazer com dois laços, um contando até 12 (tamanho de cada pessoa) e o outro usando um **Count()** na string e percorrendo até o final, mas estou com dificuldades. Teria como dar um exemplo? Ou se preferir posso abrir outra pergunta.

Comment: Abre outra porque o problema não é o mesmo, vai virar bagunça. Eu já vou começar montar ele para postar.