# Percorrer uma lista de caracteres

Tags: c#, .net, string

Possuo um método que verifica a quantidade de caracteres em uma *string*, e separa os mesmos em variáveis com as informações como pode ser visto [neste exemplo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/kTuN9W).

O problema é quando possuir uma lista de dados na *string*.

Esses dados serão separados sempre com uma contagem de 12 caracteres. A cada 12 caracteres inicia um novo dado na *string*.

Como no exemplo utilizo esta *string*:

```
var exemplo = "13032015joao";
```

Tenho como saída:

```
13 
03 
2015 
joao
```

Como proceder quando estiver outros dados nessa *string*.

```
var exemplo = "13032015joao14032014Juca";
```

Preciso que a saída seja:

```
13
03
2015
joao

14
03
2014
Juca
```

E repetindo a cada vez que essa *string* se repetisse.

Comment: @Marconi Não. Essa string irá alterar a cada repetição. O que necessito é separar esses dados a cada 12 caracteres.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para separar os blocos. Depois que separa os blocos você aplica a separação dos campos individuais como mostrado na sua [outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/54224/101).

```
using System;
using static System.Console;
using System.Collections.Generic;
                    
public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var exemplo = "13032015joao14032015Juca23032015Joao24032015Jose";
        var partes = SplitBlocks(exemplo, 12);
        foreach(var parte in partes) WriteLine(parte);
        WriteLine();
        exemplo = "13032015joao14032015Juca23032015Joao24032015Jose1234";
        partes = SplitBlocksPartial(exemplo, 12);
        foreach(var parte in partes) {
            WriteLine(parte);
        }
    }
    public static List<String> SplitBlocks(string texto, int tamanho) {
        var partes = new List<String>();
        var posicao = 0;
        var total = texto.Length;
        while(total >= posicao + tamanho) {
            partes.Add(texto.Substring(posicao, tamanho));
            posicao += tamanho;
        }
        return partes;
    }
    public static List<String> SplitBlocksPartial(string texto, int tamanho) {
        var partes = new List<String>();
        var posicao = 0;
        var total = texto.Length;
        while(total >= posicao) {
            if (total >= posicao + tamanho) partes.Add(texto.Substring(posicao, tamanho));
            else partes.Add(texto.Substring(posicao));
            posicao += tamanho;
        }
        return partes;
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/2tRotg). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Hs9Qg5). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/SplitBlock.cs).

Fiz uma versão alternativa se acontecer um caso em que o bloco pode não estar completo e ele deve ser pego mesmo assim. Acho que você não precisa dele, mas está aí para quem precisar.

Exemplo juntando as duas soluções:

```
using System;
using static System.Console;
using System.Collections.Generic;
                    
public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var exemplo = "13032015joao14032015Juca23032015Joao24032015Jose";
        var blocos = SplitBlocks(exemplo, 12);
        foreach(var bloco in blocos) {
            var colunas = SplitFixed(bloco, new List<int>() { 2, 2, 4, 4});
            foreach(var coluna in colunas) WriteLine(coluna);
            WriteLine();
        }
    }
    public static List<String> SplitBlocks(string texto, int tamanho) {
        var partes = new List<String>();
        var posicao = 0;
        var total = texto.Length;
        while(total >= posicao + tamanho) {
            partes.Add(texto.Substring(posicao, tamanho));
            posicao += tamanho;
        }
        return partes;
    }
    public static List<String> SplitFixed(string texto, List<int> tamanhos) {
        var partes = new List<String>();
        var posicao = 0;
        foreach(var tamanho in tamanhos) {
            partes.Add(texto.Substring(posicao, tamanho));
            posicao += tamanho;
        }
        return partes;
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/RIbRj9). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qC5cgB). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/SplitBlock2.cs).

Dá para fazer um método que já retorne uma lista de listas com todas as partes já separadas em um algoritmo único. Eventualmente poderia usar um *array* ao invés de uma lista se houvesse necessidade mas em geral listas são preferíveis.

Comment: Era exatamente isso, obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Debugando o código, eu vejo que a cada parte, ele adiciona um **\r\n** antes da nova parte. Teria como retirar?

Comment: Isto não faz sentido, nada do código indica adicionar qualquer caractere extra. É provável que o texto que você está trabalhando já tenha isto. Aí o problema é diferente do que você descreveu.

Comment: Peço desculpas. Ao ler o arquivo TXT estava adicionando estes caracteres ao fim de cada bloco e eu não havia percebido.

Answer (score 1):

Há vários modos para se fazer isso, a ideia geralmente é percorrer a *string* e a cada *n* caracteres obter o bloco com o método [`String.Substring()`](http://www.dotnetperls.com/substring) passando como parâmetro a posição inicial e o tamanho do bloco atual, e por fim, adicioná-lo num *array*.

A versão utilizando [`for`](http://www.dotnetperls.com/for) da função `SplitBlocks` da [resposta do Maniero](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/54236/6454):

```
static List<String> DividirBlocos(string texto, int blocos){
    var partes = new List<String>();
    int tamanho = texto.Length;
    // Incrementa "i" conforme o valor de "blocos". 0, 12, 24, 36...
    for (int i = 0; i < tamanho; i += blocos){
       if (i + blocos > tamanho) blocos = tamanho - i;
       partes.Add(texto.Substring(i, blocos));
    }
    return partes;
}
```

Exemplo funcional no [**Ideone**](https://ideone.com/YCju9p).

Uma outra alternativa que pode ser utilizada é através de uma consulta usando [LINQ](http://www.dotnetperls.com/linq):

```
static IEnumerable<string> DividirBlocos(string texto, double blocos){
    return Enumerable.Range(0, (int)Math.Ceiling(texto.Length / blocos)) 
       .Select(i => new string(texto
           .Skip(i * (int)blocos)
           .Take((int)blocos)
           .ToArray()));
}
```

Exemplo funcional no [**Ideone**](https://ideone.com/LwZT6b).

Com o método [`Enumerable.Range`](http://www.dotnetperls.com/enumerable-range) é obtido uma gama de valores, o [`Math.Ceiling`](http://www.dotnetperls.com/math-ceiling) é usado para arrendondar para cima o resultado da divisão entre o *tamanho do texto* e a quantidade de *blocos*, resultado este que será a quantidade de pedaços obtidos do texto.

Na próxima linha tem o [`.Select`](http://www.dotnetperls.com/select) que é utilizado para selecionar cada pedaço e aplicar uma ação sobre ele, o [`.Skip`](http://www.dotnetperls.com/skip) é utilizado para *ignorar* certa quantidade de caracteres e o [`.Take`](http://www.dotnetperls.com/take) é usado para *recuperar* determinada quantidade de caracteres.

**Nota**: É necessário incluir os *namespaces* `System.Collections.Generic` e `System.Linq`.

Uma outra forma de fazer isso também pode ser através de [expressões regulares](http://www.dotnetperls.com/regex):

```
List<string> partes = new List<string>(Regex.Split(texto, @"(?<=\G.{12})",
RegexOptions.Multiline));
```

Exemplo funcional no [**Ideone**](https://ideone.com/2wCVba).

Expressões regulares nesse caso deve ser provavelmente a mais ineficiente, além de menor desempenho.

A [âncora](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/h5181w5w%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) `\G` é usada para dizer que a correspondência deve começar na posição onde a correspondência anterior terminou, o ponto (`.`) é usado para capturar qualquer caractere, e por fim, o `{12}` é usado para delimitar a quantidade de caracteres que queremos retornar.

**Nota**: É necessário incluir o *namespace* `System.Text.RegularExpressions`.